# Trying to use WithArg in GMock code; error says it doesn't exist

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I am trying to use `WithArg` in some test code. The code that I am trying to compile looks like this:

```
using ::testing::_;
using ::testing::Invoke;
using ::testing::WithArg;

EXPECT_CALL(myMock, MockMethodThatTakesAString(_))
                   .WithArg<0>(Invoke(this, &TestClass::FunctionThatTakesAString))
                   .Times(4);
```

When I try to compile this, I get the error

`error: ‘class testing::internal::TypedExpectation<void(const std::basic_string<char>&)>’ has no member named ‘WithArg’`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `.WillRepeatedly(WithArg<0>(Invoke(this, &TestClass::FunctionThatTakesAString))).Times(4)`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Doing that changes to a run-time error of `Failure
.Times() cannot appear after .InSequence(), .WillOnce(), .WillRepeatedly(), or .RetiresOnSaturation().`

Comment: move `Times` before `WillRepeatedly`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Ah but putting `Times(4)` before `WillRepeatedly` does work. Thanks!

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Perhaps write up an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WithArg<N>` is an action adapter, not a member function. To use it, make it an action inside a `WillRepeatedly` clause:

```
EXPECT_CALL( myMock, MockMethodThatTakesAString(_) )
       .Times(4)
       .WillRepeatedly(WithArg<0>(Invoke(this
                                       , &TestClass::FunctionThatTakesAString)));
```